# End call, don't return to app automatic in iphone 3.1 version

Tags: iphone, openurl

my app use openURL to have a call, but when I end call, it will not return to my app automatic in iphone 3.1

Anyone know that?It's a bug of iphone 3.1?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did it return in 3.0 or earlier versions?

Comment: Although Govind is correct but also have a look at this post. You dont need to add webview to your view: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317783/return-to-app-behavior-after-phone-call-different-in-native-code-than-uiwebview

Answer (score 3):

It's not a bug, it's how it works. Once you use openURL to transfer control to another app such as the Phone, SMS, Mail or Safari, your app is closed and control transferred to the app you specified in your URL. When the user is done with the app you invoked, closing it will not reopen your application.

You may modify your application so that if the user receives an incoming call and decides to answer it, control is returned to your app when the user terminates the call. But this is of course different from what you asked for.

Comment: In iphone 2.2.1 or 3.0, It will return my app automatic, but 3.1 don't.
It's different between old version and new version.
Anybody know this?
Thank you very much!

Comment: For those who have access to Apple's Developer Forums (requires a paid iPhone developer membership), here's a statement from Apple staff that this change was indeed intended and not a bug: https://devforums.apple.com/message/128046#128046 "if you want the capability for your application to be relaunched after a call, then file an enhancement request".

Answer (score 0):

It does appear behavior has changed (for the better in my opinion)